# dynamically update content with setTimeout node jade express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

hello I am new to node and would like to have html content update dynamically every say second. I am able to update a value with set timeout the following way, however I must refresh the page in order to see the change

```
var jade = require('jade');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

function getName(currentName) {
    return currentName + " more hello world ";
}

function updateApp(data) {

    data.name = getName(data.name); // get desired text
    app.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render("index", {data: data});
    });
    setTimeout(function() {updateApp(data)}, 1000); // schedule values update
}

app.set('views', __dirname+'/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');


var startValue = "hello world"
var data = {
    name: startValue
}
//start app
updateApp(data);

app.listen(3000);
```

where

```
html
    head
        script(type='text/javascript').
            var data = !{data};
    body
        h1 
            text= data.name
```

is my jade template. Is there a simple way to change this so that the updated text is displayed without a page refresh?

Comment: I think that you should learn more about JavaScript itself before trying to expand on your skills. You're using setTimeout wrong. A setInterval would be what your logic is looking for. Also, you're using an asynchronous function without waiting for it to complete before moving on. You'll want to structure your code in a way that uses callback functions in order to handle the asynchronous methods properly. Personally I don't really use any JS "libraries" without good justification. AJAX is surprisingly simple to accomplish using native JS.

Comment: @JonathanGray can you recommend good resources/tutorials? I have used javascript quite a bit but am new to node and asynchronous methods

Comment: I can't give you any good resourced for node, but asynchronous programming just takes a little bit of getting used to. You will have to remember that JS will not wait for an async command to complete before it moves on to the next command. This makes return statements pretty much useless. What you have to do is use a callback function as one of the input variables to the asynchronous function. Then when the async function completes, call the callback function with the result. It can be tedious doing this for an entire script though as every function in the chain also has to handle callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

[Click here for my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j64ptfnu/)

```
function loadXMLDoc(url, method, callback) {
    var xmlhttp = window.XMLHttpRequest?xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
              if(xmlhttp.status==200) {
              callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
              } else callback(false);
          }
      }
    xmlhttp.open(method,url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

var UpdateAlgo = function() {
    loadXMLDoc("http://ajax-url-here/", "POST",
        function(result) {
            if(result !== false) {
            document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = result;
            }
        AfterUpdate();
        });
    }

var AfterUpdate = function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        UpdateAlgo();
        }, 1000);
    }

AfterUpdate();
```

I think you should be able to learn a bit from this